# Is it safe to plant shrubs or flowers in the soil above my septic tank?

Tags: safety, septic-tanks, planting

I have a septic system that has a tank underneath my front lawn. This is an eye-sore as the access points are clearly visible to anyone coming down our driveway. I would like to plant some shrubs/flowers around the access points to hide them. Is it safe to do this? I don't want to plant trees or anything crazy.

NOTE: I am not going to actually **cover** the access points. I just want to hide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem. Your septic tank should be full enclosed and the vent/access pipes should be sealed. It's unlikely that roots from small shrubs will make their way in and cause clogs.